# Axios proper request

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

Answered.

So I'm tasked with building TodoService class, for http Rest API requests. I'm calling instanse of  TodoService class method --> getAllTodos, which inturn is callingextended method get(config). I undestand that `todoService.getAllTodos` returns a promise. Also I pass `todoService.getAllTodos` as second parameter to useQuery React hook from React-Query library.
Question: if inside useQuery hook I pass callback that returns invoked  `todoService.getAllTodos` - all works - I recieve data from server, If I pass only `todoService.getAllTodos` to be invoked - error: TypeError: this.get is not a function at Object.getAllTodos.
Its either useQuery arguments related or the fact that method returns promise.
Please Help me understand this issue.

```
import { HttpSerivce } from './http.servicies';

class TodoService extends HttpSerivce {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  async getAllTodos() {
    return this.get({ url: 'todos' });
  }
}

export const todoService = new TodoService();
```

```
import axios from 'axios';

type Config = {
  url: string;
};

export class HttpSerivce {
  baseUrl: string | undefined;

  fetchingService: any;

  apiVersion: string;

  constructor(baseUrl = 'http://localhost:4200', fetchingService = axios, apiVersion = 'api') {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    this.fetchingService = fetchingService;
    this.apiVersion = apiVersion;
  }

  // private getFullApiUrl(url: string) {
  //   return `${this.baseUrl}/${this.apiVersion}/${url}`;
  // }

  async get(config: Config) {
    const response = await this.fetchingService.get(`http://localhost:4200/api/${config.url}`);
    return response.data;
  }
}
```

is working

```
import { todoService } from '../../../servecies/todo.servecies';

export const TodoContainer = () => {
  const { data, error, isLoading, isError } = useQuery('todos', () => todoService.getAllTodos());
```

is not working

```
export const TodoContainer = () => {
  const { data, error, isLoading, isError } = useQuery('todos', todoService.getAllTodos);
```

Edited:
error was here

```
 getAllTodos = async () => {
    return this.get({ url: 'todos' });
  }
```

Comment: Try changing the `getAllTodos` function into an ES6 one: `getAllTodos = async () => { //Do you thing }` and let me know if it fixes your issue.

Comment: That totally fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have given the direct solution in the comment, but posting an answer as well to explain the reasoning.

The reason for the error you're getting is the use of the `this` keyword, which is a common cause of trouble in class-based React components. The scope of `this` varies inside a member function, and we can't always rely on it to point to the class instance. At least that is the case if the function in question has been defined using ES5 syntax.

The workaround to this, while still using ES5, is to "bind" the context of the class to the function, like so:

```
class TodoService extends HttpSerivce {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.getAllTodos = this.getAllTodos.bind(this);
  }

  async getAllTodos() {
    return this.get({ url: 'todos' });
  }
}
```

Doing the above will preserve the context of `this` when the function is called from elsewhere.

A more concise, and probably more effective, alternative is to switch to ES6, which takes care of preserving the context of `this` automatically for you.

```
class TodoService extends HttpSerivce {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  const getAllTodos = () => {
    return this.get({ url: 'todos' });
  }
}
```